# how to make input select option is not responsive using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using input select control for my web application with bootstrap. I have used some content in this control below is the control i used.

```html
 <div class="form-group input-group" id="Div2" style="width:100%">
             <select id="sel1" class="form-control input-lg">
                 <option>--Select Question--</option>
                 <option>What is your pet name in childhood?</option>
                    <option>What is your favorite school teacher name in school?</option>
                   <option>What is your town name where you born?</option>
                    <option>Who is your favorite actor?</option>
                    <option>Which mobile you like most?</option>
             </select>
        </div>
```

but when i am seeing mobile then it's content is showing outside from control.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<div class="container">
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel2">input-lg</label>
      <select class="form-control input-lg" id="sel2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Gurkan, Thanks for your reply, which code i have pasted i want with that code make responsive for mobile.